# Visual Studio on Mac with Unreal Engine (last version)

Tags: visual-studio-2017, unreal-engine4

I would like to know if there are any form of use UE on mac without Xcode. I would like to use Visual Studio 2017 like main IDE to programming my project without install Xcode. Thanks in advance.

PD: my English is not very good, excuse me if I have some mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, Visual Studio for Mac has no support for C++, as [stated in various places](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ef99e9f5-2a48-423b-b6c0-fa5617d7c63d/how-do-i-get-c-to-work-on-visual-studio-for-mac?forum=visualstudiogeneral):

> Visual Studio for Mac is a developer environment optimized for building mobile and cloud apps with Xamarin and .NET. There has no option to create C++ project in this version
>   some other community members reported this suggestion to the Visual Studio Product Team, please check this: [Support C++ in Visual Studio for Mac](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17141708-support-c-in-visual-studio-for-mac) and you can vote it, then waiting for the feedback from the Visual Studio Product Team.

Also, [as reformulated in the UE forums](https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/c-gameplay-programming/121490-visual-studio-instead-of-xcode-on-macos) it reads:

> Looks like vs for mac is just a rebranded xamarin studio, and only supports C#, no C++.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I misread the question, look for the other answer I gave, Visual Studio for Mac is C# only.

But, since the recent [Unreal Engine 4.18 release](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Support/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_18/) (2017/10/23), you can use Visual Studio Code under macOS, Linux, and Windows.
You need to install .NET Core 2.0 runtimes, and some other dependencies for full C++ support and debugging.

From [the release notes](https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Support/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_18/):

> To use Visual Studio Code to build and debug all project types, some additional extensions are required. On all platforms, make sure the Microsoft C/C++ extension, and the C# extension are installed. On Linux and Mac, the "Mono Debug" extension is required to debug C# projects, and the “LLDB Debugger” extension is required to debug C++ projects.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer but in the release notes doesn’t say nothing about Visual Studio 2017, it just talk about Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake! I read Visual Studio and jumped on the obvious answer of Visual Studio Code (that I would like to try asap).